# How to import OpenSSL moudle in /art/runtime/oat_file_assistant.cc?

Tags: c++, openssl, include, android-source

I want to modify the “/art/runtime/oat_file_assistant.cc” in the source code of Android system to use the SHA1 function of OpenSSL. However, during compilation, it is prompted that the "openssl/sha.h" file cannot be found. I don't know much about C++, how to use OpenSSL correctly in “/art/runtime/oat_file_assistant.cc”？Thanks very much。

Here are the include statements

```cpp
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#incldue <openssl/pem.h>
```

fatal error: "openssl/sha.h" file not found

Comment: These are relative paths. You need to tell your compiler the starting points from where to look for those relative paths. That's compiler-dependent, though. GCC uses `-I` option for. So if complete path is `x/y/z/openssl/sha.h`, you'd compile with `gcc -Ix/y/z source.cpp`

Comment: Thank you. But I use " make " comand to compile Android system, not GCC, So I can't add parameters to GCC。

Comment: `make` is not a compiler, but it invokes one. Look inside your makefile, there you'll need to add the appropriate flags to the compiler invocation. GCC was just an example, you might use any other compiler, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, let me try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the SSL library to the `static_libs` or `shared_libs` of `libart_defaults` in `art/runtime/Android.bp`.

Example:

```
cc_defaults {
    name: "libart_defaults",
    [...]
    shared: {
        shared_libs: [
            [ ... ]
            "libcrypto",
        ],
    }
}
```

Androids build tooling (`Soong`) will take care of adding the `-I` flags to `gcc`.